Jumper on 100 Mbps Ethernet
Is it possible to pass a 100BASE-TX signal (100 Mbps Ethernet, over 2 differential pairs) through jumpers (one per wire), in order to allow the user to select Ethernet or serial for a given connector?
By jumpers, I mean the usual 2.54 mm pitch jumpers used for configuration, like: 
(from Altium website).
I'm intending to place those jumpers between the magnetic and the connector.
Is it OK or will I degrade too much the signal?
I suppose using surface mount pins is probably better than though hole pins?
In case it's OK for 100 Mbps, can I also use jumpers for 1 Gbps Ethernet (1000BASE-T)?

If they are in pairs in series with the line, then no unbalanced length is added, only a little uncoupled length.  Crosstalk, CMRR, etc. may be impaired slightly, depending on layout.  Even gig isn't particularly fast, a few 100 MHz analog bandwidth is sufficient -- the rest is made up in multilevel coding, and full duplex four-lane signaling.  Quite modest stub, mismatch and uncoupled lengths are tolerable (cm+).

Yes, I was planning to use the jumpers in pairs in series (so no unbalanced length added, some small uncoupled length (<1cm)). So it should be OK?
